# Individual row and column spacing in matrix environment

Tags: matrices, tikz-matrix

I know that one can change the row and column separation in the `\matrix` command with `row sep`, respectively `column sep`. But how do one change the separation for a specific row or column only?

That is; having different spacing between between different rows? Also, how do one do the same for column spacing?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[column sep=5mm, row sep=5mm]
    {
        % Row 1
        \node {1:1};&\node {1:2};&\node {1:3};&\node {1:4};;\\
        % Row 2
        \node {2:1};&\node {2:2};&\node {2:3};&\node {2:4};\\
        % Row 3
        \node {3:1};&\node {3:2};&\node {3:3};&\node {3:4};\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a MWE, so we could answer better

Comment: @Puck Updated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the separation to zero; then use `&[<width>]` in the first row for column separation and `\\[<width>]` for row separation.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[column sep=0mm, row sep=0mm]{
    % Row 1
    \node {1:1}; &[5mm] \node {1:2}; &[10mm] \node {1:3}; &[10mm] \node {1:4}; \\[5mm]
    % Row 2
    \node {2:1}; &      \node {2:2}; &       \node {2:3}; &       \node {2:4}; \\[10mm]
    % Row 3
    \node {3:1}; &      \node {3:2}; &       \node {3:3}; &       \node {3:4}; \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**ROW SEPARATION**

For the row spacing, instead of specifying a matrix-wide row sep, use the optional argument to `\\` to accomplish row specific skips.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[column sep=5mm]
    {
        % Row 1
        \node {1:1};&\node {1:2};&\node {1:3};&\node {1:4};;\\[5mm]
        % Row 2
        \node {2:1};&\node {2:2};&\node {2:3};&\node {2:4};\\[10mm]
        % Row 3
        \node {3:1};&\node {3:2};&\node {3:3};&\node {3:4};\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, you can keep a default `row sep` and specify the deviation from it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[column sep=5mm, row sep=5mm]
    {
        % Row 1
        \node {1:1};&\node {1:2};&\node {1:3};&\node {1:4};;\\
        % Row 2
        \node {2:1};&\node {2:2};&\node {2:3};&\node {2:4};\\[5mm]
        % Row 3
        \node {3:1};&\node {3:2};&\node {3:3};&\node {3:4};\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**COLUMN SEPARATION**

As to the issue of column separation, I know of no easy way to accomplish this.  In the *particular* example provided by the OP, the column gaps are all *integer multiples* of each other.  If that were always the case, one can just add blank columns:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[column sep=5mm, row sep=5mm]
    {
        % Row 1
        \node {1:1};&\node {1:2};&&\node {1:3};&\node {1:4};;\\
        % Row 2
        \node {2:1};&\node {2:2};&&\node {2:3};&\node {2:4};\\[5mm]
        % Row 3
        \node {3:1};&\node {3:2};&&\node {3:3};&\node {3:4};\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I presume that is too much to hope for.  The best I could do for the general case is provide the `\knode` macro that has an optional kern built in.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\knode[2][0]{\node{#2\kern#1mm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[column sep=5mm, row sep=5mm]
    {
        % Row 1
        \node {1:1};&\knode[5]{1:2};&\node {1:3};&\node {1:4};;\\
        % Row 2
        \node {2:1};&\knode[5]{2:2};&\node {2:3};&\node {2:4};\\[5mm]
        % Row 3
        \node {3:1};&\knode[5]{3:2};&\node {3:3};&\node {3:4};\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That solved my question about row spacing, thank you. But I was not clear enough about wanting the same for column separation. Could you update your answer with that too?

Comment: @RobinHellmers Please see updated answer.